# Pandas stack multiple dataframes vertically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the two dataframes, but it would be much more later, that I would like to stack vertically. Right now they stack but I think the unindexed name and date mess things up.

`final_df = pd.concat(all_dfs)`
and
`final_df = pd.concat(all_dfs, ignore_index=True)`
but neither work. Further information is below.

df1:

```
  Mohammed  10/06/22
0   Unit 1        72
1   Unit 2         0
2   Unit 3         0
3   Unit 4         0
4   Unit 5         0
5   Unit 6         0
```

df2:

```
    Mason  10/06/22
0  Unit 1       100
1  Unit 2       100
2  Unit 3        44
3  Unit 4         0
4  Unit 5         0
5  Unit 6         0
```

When I append the dfs into a list and then run:

```
final_df = pd.concat(all_dfs)
print(final_df)
```

I get:

```
  Mohammed  10/06/22   Mason
0   Unit 1        72     NaN
1   Unit 2         0     NaN
2   Unit 3         0     NaN
3   Unit 4         0     NaN
4   Unit 5         0     NaN
5   Unit 6         0     NaN
0      NaN       100  Unit 1
1      NaN       100  Unit 2
2      NaN        44  Unit 3
3      NaN         0  Unit 4
4      NaN         0  Unit 5
5      NaN         0  Unit 6
```

I want to get:

```
  Mohammed  10/06/22
0   Unit 1        72
1   Unit 2         0
2   Unit 3         0
3   Unit 4         0
4   Unit 5         0
5   Unit 6         0
    Mason  10/06/22
0  Unit 1       100
1  Unit 2       100
2  Unit 3        44
3  Unit 4         0
4  Unit 5         0
5  Unit 6         0
```

Comment: Try `pd.concat([df,df1],join='inner',keys=['Mohammed','Mason'])`

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew That's pretty close. I'm only left with index and percentages. The `Unit` column is no longer there.

Comment: Yes, it's because it's merged based on the union of the unit column values, so if you are not keen on the `unit`, you can use this as your code

Comment: You're desired output is not a valid dataframe structure.  Everyone row in a dataframe must have an index and you have only one column header at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You desired output is not a dataframe.  However the close we came come is like this:

```
pd.concat([d.T.reset_index().T for d in [df1, df2]])
```

Output:

```
              0         1
index  Mohammed  10/06/22
0        Unit 1        72
1        Unit 2         0
2        Unit 3         0
3        Unit 4         0
4        Unit 5         0
5        Unit 6         0
index     Mason  10/06/22
0        Unit 1       100
1        Unit 2       100
2        Unit 3        44
3        Unit 4         0
4        Unit 5         0
5        Unit 6         0
```

Or using to_string.

```
print(pd.concat([d.T.reset_index().T for d in [df1, df2]]).to_string(index=False))

       0        1
Mohammed 10/06/22
  Unit 1       72
  Unit 2        0
  Unit 3        0
  Unit 4        0
  Unit 5        0
  Unit 6        0
   Mason 10/06/22
  Unit 1      100
  Unit 2      100
  Unit 3       44
  Unit 4        0
  Unit 5        0
  Unit 6        0
```